# Why did I fail this audit review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I was in the Low-Quality review queue and I came upon an answer that even though it lacks explanation I thought it could still pass as an ok answer. However, after clicking "Looks OK" I received the following message:

[image: spam question]

Any idea why that is? Especially considering that the justification was for "Spam/offensive content".

[Here's the link of the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26234498)

Comment: As always, click the link to the right and open the answer in a new page and you'll see it's an audit right away...

Comment: @HereticMonkey what does that mean though? Not sure I understand.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Heretic means if you click the link to open the answer, you would have seen that it was already deleted, indicating that it's an audit

Comment: It’s a wrong answer but none of the URLs look like spam. BTW, the user has been suspended for almost a year.

Comment: My question still stands though. Why did my "Looks OK" is considered the wrong answer when the original post doesn't look like Spam or offensive?

Comment: *My question still stands though.* I know. Just thought the suspension was noteworthy. Maybe there were links that weren’t visible?

Answer (score 18):

Let's unpack how we got to this point. The *original answer* was not spam (and the user has plenty of decent answers). Apparently an anonymous user edited in spam and [people asleep at the wheel approved it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16868992). A moderator then came back and disapproved the edit (and probably handed out review bans).

What's weird here is that on May 4, 2020 (some 3 years after the spam edit) [the question was red-flagged by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39264100/timeline) (one downvote and deleted by Community without a user destroy). The [user is suspended for a year](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6261392/jaydeep-gondaliya) so it might be related somehow. It's been used as an audit one other time (and I can only assume that reviewer clicked into the answer to see it was deleted since they passed).

I've raised a mod flag to see if they can shed any light, but it's a bad audit because it's a bad red flag.

Answer (score 11):

While the actions of the user may be spammy in nature, this particular post should not have been spam-flagged since that causes it to be eligible as an (incorrect) audit and only cause confusion.

I've re-deleted it manually so it should no longer be an audit.

Comment: Why should it be deleted at all? It's not great quality, but it's not bad enough for deletion, right?