# Very old posts started getting used for review audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, review-audits

Using old posts for audits is troublesome. This was covered a while ago in discussions at MSE and resulted in [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198877/dont-use-very-old-posts-for-audits/198919#comment631103_198919) limiting the age of these posts:

> #### ALL audit posts are limited to things posted in the past 30 days

But several recent complaints show that several years old posts started being used for audits yet again - for example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397772/why-did-i-fail-this-audit-review), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388914/839601) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397398/too-many-unfair-review-audits?noredirect=1#comment769799_397398) (showing by the way yet again that using old posts for audits is really troublesome, for the very same reasons that were already discussed at MSE in the past).

I suggest to change the system back to limiting the age of audit posts as it was decided at MSE.

---

<sup>I have a suspicion that age requirement was dropped because it didn't work well in audits that were later added at some smaller sites (which may have just not enough traffic to provide reasonable selection of posts limited to only 30 days). If this is the case, then Stack Overflow should get a site-specific setting to recover the age requirement that works for our site. Though frankly, having audits that are several years old looks troublesome for any site no matter how small, smaller sites probably need to have their own audit post age limit too, maybe something like few months.</sup>

Comment: I guess it's now: Have been active in the last 30 days.

Comment: @BDL that's a good guess, thank you. Doesn't make it less of a bug, but plausible explanation of how it happened anyway

Comment: (FWIW my motivation for proposing this bugfix is only to decrease meta noise and see less complaints about such audits. Personally I am not affected by these in any way - I fail audits once in every 200, maybe 300 reviews, and reason for my failures is always my mistake (insufficient attention) and it has nothing to do with the age of audit posts)

Comment: Just FYI, it seems that the issue here is that *current* deletion (red flags or otherwise) are triggering audits on old questions.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been caught by a regression test?

Comment: @Peter Where did you get the idea that Stack Exchange uses regression tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been fixed. Details:

- Issue here had to do with the way that audits are selected for users - this can either be drawn from the pool of questions that have already been used as audits on the site (where this user hasn't interacted with the post or review), or can be a newly minted review audit.
- The new audit selection was abiding by the "only posts from the last X days" (where default for sites is X=30, though individual sites with lower review volumes can look back further).
- The "take from existing audits" was not abiding by this filter. It is now - will only select from existing audits if the audit is on a post created in the last X days.

> shown an old audit
> "that should not be" remarked gnat
> filtering now fixed